# «Insert» con PHP y MySQL vía AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estoy aprendiendo un poco de jQuery y AJAX. Necesito hacer un `insert` a mysql con php poo y AJAX(o jquery-ajax, lo que sea mejor). Este es mi modelo:

```
class PacienteMySqlDAO implements PacienteDAO{
    public function insert($paciente){
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO paciente (rutpaciente, rut, nombre, apellidopaterno, apellidomaterno, fechanacimiento, direccion, telefono, correlectronico, ciudad) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $sqlQuery = new SqlQuery($sql);

        $sqlQuery->setNumber($paciente->rutpaciente);
        $sqlQuery->set($paciente->rut);
        $sqlQuery->set($paciente->nombre);
        $sqlQuery->set($paciente->apellidopaterno);
        $sqlQuery->set($paciente->apellidomaterno);
        $sqlQuery->set($paciente->fechanacimiento);
        $sqlQuery->set($paciente->direccion);
        $sqlQuery->set($paciente->telefono);
        $sqlQuery->set($paciente->correlectronico);
        $sqlQuery->setNumber($paciente->ciudad);

        $id = $this->executeInsert($sqlQuery);  
        $paciente->id = $id;
        return $id;
    }
}
```

controlador:

```
class Pacientes extends PacienteMySqlDAO
{   
    public function nuevoPaciente($pac){
        $objPac = new PacienteMySqlDAO();   
        $id = $objPac->insert($pac);
    }
}
```

He visto varios ejemplos pero ninguno con poo y menos mvc,en todos los ejemplos de internet AJAX ejecuta un archivo php dentro del mismo directorio,pero aquí es diferente. Espero que me hayan podido entender y me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta o ayuda que necesitas?

Comment: como hago el insert usando los metodos que indique y ajax del lado del cliente, o mejor dicho como le mando los parametros que mi consulta requiere usando ajax?

Comment: Comprendo que no tienes reputación suficiente en el sitio para poder comentar en las preguntas, pero añadir un comentario como respuesta no es bueno. Seguramente tu respuesta acabará cerrada y puede que con votos negativos.

Comment: Hola @daniel2016. Alvaro está explicando la regla a Harol. Si no conoces las reglas del sitio, tienes los sitios de ayuda el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y el [centro de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @daniel2016. , ¿podrías comprobar si alguna de las respuestas soluciona tu problema? recuerda votar positivamente aquellas respuestas que, aunque no sean la respuesta que marques como correcta, te hayan ayudado o aclarado dudas. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

> He visto varios ejemplos pero ninguno con poo y menos mvc,en todos los ejemplos de internet AJAX ejecuta un archivo php dentro del mismo directorio,pero aquí es diferente

No entiendo muy bien con ejemplos POO Y MVC, lo ideal siempre seria que llamaras a una URL local (del proyecto) o bien una URL de algun servicio en su servidor, enviar los datos necesarios para esta llamada y en el servidor agregar la inserción de este objeto Persona, donde ahi ocupes toda tu logica orientada a objetos

Si deseas que tu data en AJAX pase como un objeto, puedes crear algo asi :

```
var persona = {
      rut : $('#rut'),
      nombre : $('#nombre'),
      apellido_paterno : $('#apellidoPaterno'),
      apellido_materno : $('#apellidoMaterno'),
      ...
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "/insertarPersona",
    data: persona,
    success: function(data) {

    }});
```

Para que en tu servicio o funcion PHP recibas estos datos y puedas trabajar con campos, indices y asi respetas la arquitectura que tiene tu modelo Persona en este caso u cualquier otro.

```
public function nuevoPaciente($json){
    $persona_json = json_decode($json, true);
    //En esta parte persona_json tiene el formato de array
    $paciente = new Paciente();
    $paciente->rut = $persona_json['rut'];
    $paciente->nombre = $persona_json['nombre'];
    $paciente->apellidopaterno = $persona_json['apellido_paterno'];
    //Y asi con todos tus campos, 
    $id = $objPac->insert($paciente);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada JQuery y AJAX corren del lado del cliente (front-end) y el código que corre en el servidor (PHP en este caso) es el back-end.

Si lo que quieres hacer es un insert en MySQL del lado del cliente con AJAX deberías de usar simplemente una llamada AJAX en una función que sea devuelta por un form o un botón y que esté escrita en un archivo JavaScript, un ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", //puede ser GET,POST o el verbo HTTP que necesites
        url: "api/pacientes/insertar", //es la url que te lleva a la función de inserción
        data: {
            nombre:"Juan",apellido:"Gonzales",...,ciudad:"México" //un arreglo con los datos de entrada de tu función
        },
        success: function(data) {
          // si todo va bien, aquí ejecutas un alert, devuelves true o alguna otra cosa
        }});
```